# Xcode - Return from Detail View Controller To Master View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode

Within Xcode i want to be able to return from detail view controller to the master view controller on a click of a button (not the master button that is there by default)

The code for going from master > detail is;

```
  DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
    [controller setDetailItem:message];
```

However what is the code for the other way around?

Comment: try: [self.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Hi, Again this did not work, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

can you add how you call that detail view controller from master view controller? If you are using navigation controller you should use `self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` or you should use dismiss as written before.

Comment: Hi @kocakmstf, There is no other code to go with what i posted above, with that code the detail view controller is displayed. I'm very new to all of this therefore sorry i cannot be of much help